# JPA cascade Delete meaning

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

What's the meaning of this annotation?

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.DELETE)
  List<Patient> list;
```

In particular cascade delete, does it mean that if I delete an entity in which is one to many are deleted all entities of list of Patients or viceversa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that if I delete an entity in which is one to many are
>   deleted all entities of list of Patients or viceversa?

Yes. it means  `Patient` record will be deleted.

Comment: and if I've, in a single entity A, multiple relations (many to one) towards an entity B (annotated with one to many)? Do I've to put an annotation for each occurrence of A in B?

Answer (score 4):

cascade type delete mean when delete record from parent class then also delete record from child class
cascade on null delete record from parent then set the null in reference key null